# get name of currenttab and use that text to replace the header text

Tags: javascript

I have this html for some tabs. I want to get the text name of the "currenttab" and use that text to replace the .tabmenu span text "League Tabs". How can i do this with javascript?

```
<div class="tabmenu"><span>LEAGUE TABS</span><input id="sub100" type="checkbox"><label for="sub100"><span></span></label>
    <ul id="homepagetabs">
        <li id="tab0" onclick="javascript:show_tab('0');" class="currenttab"><a class="no-sub">Main<input id="sub100" type="checkbox"><label for="sub100"></label></a></li>
        <li id="tab1" onclick="javascript:show_tab('1');" class=""><a class="no-sub">#2<input id="sub100" type="checkbox"><label for="sub100"></label></a></li>
        <li id="tab2" onclick="javascript:show_tab('2');" class=""><a class="no-sub">11<input id="sub100" type="checkbox"><label for="sub100"></label></a></li>
        <li id="tab3" onclick="javascript:show_tab('3');" class=""><a class="no-sub">1<input id="sub100" type="checkbox"><label for="sub100"></label></a></li>
        <li id="tab4" onclick="javascript:show_tab('4');" class=""><a class="no-sub">#5<input id="sub100" type="checkbox"><label for="sub100"></label></a></li>
        <li id="tab5" onclick="javascript:show_tab('5');" class=""><a class="no-sub">#6<input id="sub100" type="checkbox"><label for="sub100"></label></a></li>
        <li id="tab6" onclick="javascript:show_tab('6');" class=""><a class="no-sub">#7<input id="sub100" type="checkbox"><label for="sub100"></label></a></li>
        <li id="tab7" onclick="javascript:show_tab('7');" class=""><a class="no-sub">#8<input id="sub100" type="checkbox"><label for="sub100"></label></a></li>
        <li id="tab8" onclick="javascript:show_tab('8');" class=""><a class="no-sub">#9<input id="sub100" type="checkbox"><label for="sub100"></label></a></li>
        <li id="tab9" onclick="javascript:show_tab('9');" class=""><a class="no-sub">#10<input id="sub100" type="checkbox"><label for="sub100"></label></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `the text name of the "currenttab"` - so what names do you expect?

Comment: in the example html , currenttab , text name is "main" , i'd like "main" to replace the text "League Tabs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your `show_tab` function, you need to get the currently-selected `<li>` item, then grab its text and copy it over to the tab menu:

```
var tabmenuSpan = document.querySelector('.tabmenu span');

function show_tab(number) {
  // code to remove/add the currenttab class
  var tabText = document.querySelector('.currenttab a').textContent;
  tabmenuSpan.textContent = tabText;
}
```